# Why the Event fires multiple times in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I checked similar questions here but the answers were not related to my issue.

I am new to C# and I am using windows forms.

[image: ScreenShot]

As show in ScreenShot, I have form1, UserControl1 and UserControl2.

- Form1 has 2 buttons (ShowUserControl1 & ShowUserControl2) and DataGridView.
- UserControl1 has button “AddRow” and textbox.
- UserControl2 has nothing.

I click “ShowUserControl2” button ShowUserControl2 show up, then I click “ShowUserControl1” button ShowUserControl1 shows up, then I enter text into texBox in UserControl1 and Click “AddRow” a new row is added and it works fine.

Now the problem is:

When I click “ShowUserControl1” then click “ShowUserControl2” then click “ShowUserControl1” again and enter text then click “AddRow” once, 2 rows are added at once in DataGridView. Click on “ShowUserControl1” 3 times and click “AddRow” once, 3 rows are added at once and so on.

I think the even handeler in Form1 (HandleTheEvent) gets executed multiple times because I click on “ShowUserControl1” multiple times as a result of switching between the UserControls. How can I prevent the even form firing multiple times? Please help. 
Thank you

Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    UserControl1 UC1 = new UserControl1();
    UserControl2 UC2 = new UserControl2();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //add user controls when form loads
        Controls.Add(UC1);
        Controls.Add(UC2);
    }


    private void ShowUC(Control value)   // Show/hide User Controls
    {
        UC1.Visible = false;
        UC2.Visible = false;

        value.Visible = true;

     }


    public void HandleTheEvent(object sender, EventArgs e) //deal with the event
    { 

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1, UC1.ReturnData, 3);

    }


    private void ShowUserControl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        ShowUC(UC1); //show User Control1
        UC1.UserControl1Event += new EventHandler(HandleTheEvent);


    }

    private void ShowUserControl2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowUC(UC2); //show User Control2
    }
}
```

UserControl1:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{

    public event EventHandler UserControl1Event;

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public string ReturnData 
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }

    }
    private void AddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserControl1Event(this, e);

    }
}
```

Comment: You are subscribing and not unsubscribing. Try `UC1.UserControl1Event -= new EventHandler(HandleTheEvent);   UC1.UserControl1Event += new EventHandler(HandleTheEvent);`

Comment: @ Giorgi Nakeuri. Can you please tell me where to place this code which you provided? thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The control is created ones, but every time `ShowUserControl1_Click` is called , you are binding the event again. This means when the `UserControl1Event` event is raised/called. the `HandleTheEvent` is called multiple times. An event is a list of handlers.

```
private void ShowUserControl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    ShowUC(UC1); //show User Control1


    UC1.UserControl1Event += new EventHandler(HandleTheEvent);


}
```

You should bind the event ones in the constructor:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    UserControl1 UC1 = new UserControl1();
    UserControl2 UC2 = new UserControl2();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        UC1.UserControl1Event += new EventHandler(HandleTheEvent);
    }
```

---

Don't forget to check if the `UserControl1Event` is assigned here:

```
private void AddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // here!
    if(UserControl1Event != null)
        UserControl1Event(this, e);
}
```

Comment: @ Jeroen van Langen . yours worked like a magic :) . But I have 2 questions please: first, Can I bind  the event in form load instead of constructor ? because in form load worked too. Second question: why do we have to check if the event is assigned since it is already assigned for sure in the constructor of Form1. please advice me. thank you

Comment: @naouf, (1) You can bind the event everywhere, but you should only bind it ones. I like to bind those within the constructor, because then I'm sure it is called only ones. (2) One of the things you'd like to achieve is reusing your code. This time you are using this event, the next time you might not want to use that event. _(for example; you're not always handling the mousedown event on every control)_ If you didn't bind a handler to an event, you'll get a `NullReferenceException` when you fire/raise/call it. Thats because you are calling a `NULL` pointer as delegate.

Comment: @ Jeroen van Langen. well explained, thank you very much.